# Tamil content not found in excel

Tags: unicode, fonts, windows-10, excel-2010, tamil

I have download a excel file in Tamil. But it not shown a exact content in Tamil. It shows like this "tUlhe;j kjpg;gPl;by; Fwpg;gplg;gl;Ls;sthW epfo;r;rpj; jpl;lj;jpd; ngau; " . What would be the problem? I don't know what Unicode or fonts i have to install. I am using MS Office 2010 and windows-10.

Comment: Do you know on what exact operating system the Excel file was generated?  The file must be encoded in the default ANSI code page for the version of Windows 10 you are using, or be encoded with UTF-8 or UTF-16 with BOM.  If encoded with the default ANSI code page of a different localized version of Windows that the one you are using to read it, that could cause the problem you are seeing.

Comment: If you solved it, answer your own question and with the solution and accept it.

Answer (score -1):

The encoding used in the excel is Bamini. to read this font you need to install fonts from same bamini encoding. or else convert those characters into Unicode encoding which is preferable for default Tamil fonts.

For converting it into unicode encoding use http://dev.neechalkaran.com/p/oovan.html